# Как массив данных PHP разложить на несколько массивов по id для дальнейшего преобразование такого массива в JSON строку?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Из базы данных получаю массив с платежными данными. Необходимо выбрать конкретные, сформировать JSON и подставить результат в JS для распределения данных по input в HTML форме.

Получаю данные таким образом:

```
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $payment_service = $row["payment_service"];

    if ($payment_service == 'PayPal'){
    $paypal_item_number = $row["id"];
    $paypal_amount = $row["amount"];
    $paypal_curr_code = $row["currency_code"];
    $validity = $row["validity"];
    $paypal_email = $row["paypal_email"];

    var_dump($row["id"]);
    var_dump($row);

    //echo json_encode($row);
    
  }
}
```

`var_dump($row["id"]);` результат:

```
string(2) "74"
string(2) "76"
string(2) "77"
```

`var_dump($row);` результат:

```
array(8) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "74"
  ["amount"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  ["currency_code"]=>
  string(3) "USD"
  ["validity"]=>
  string(2) "72"
  ["payment_service"]=>
  string(6) "PayPal"
  ["paypal_email"]=>
  string(16) "book@ya.ru"
  ["stripe_pkey"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["status"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
array(8) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "76"
  ["amount"]=>
  string(3) "100"
  ["currency_code"]=>
  string(3) "RUB"
  ["validity"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["payment_service"]=>
  string(6) "PayPal"
  ["paypal_email"]=>
  string(16) "book@ya.ru"
  ["stripe_pkey"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["status"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}...
```

Далее в форме, с помощью select выбираю нужный id

```
<option value="74">USD 10</option>    
<option value="76">RUB 100</option>   
<option value="77">RUB 500</option>
```

Еще ниже по коду, получаю значение выбранного select с помощью js

```
var select = document.getElementById("PayPalAmount");

select.addEventListener("change", function(){  
    getValue = this.value;
    // выбранный select ($row["id"]) = getValue
    //alert( getValue );
});
```

Теперь у меня есть необходимый id из select который хранится в **getValue**

Как мне вывести json в следующей части кода:

```
var array =
```

Должно быть примерно так:

```
var array = {cmd: '_xclick', business: 'book-facilitator@ya.ru', custom: '5'......};
```

Т.е., как на этапе получения данных из базы, распределить данные по `$row["id"]`, чтобы после выбранного select нужная переменная с данными конкретного **getValue** (`$row["id"]`) подставилась в код?

Например так:

```
getValue = какие-то манипуляции для получения массива с данными на основе id лежащим в getValue;
$peremennay = json_encode($row['что-то']);
var array = <?php echo $peremennay; ?>
```

где `$peremennay;` равна json строке сформированной из полученного массива данных `{cmd: '_xclick', business: 'book-facilitator@ya.ru', custom: '5'......}`

Данный код осуществляет возможность смены множества данных в одной html форме, т.е. выбираем select и json расставляет данные по input в форме, таким образом нет необходимости создавать несколько отдельных форм. Проще решения и без использования jquery не нашел.

Код целиком:

```
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
$payment_service = $row["payment_service"];

if ($payment_service == 'PayPal'){
    $paypal_item_number = $row["id"];
    $paypal_amount = $row["amount"];
    $paypal_curr_code = $row["currency_code"];
    $validity = $row["validity"];
    $paypal_email = $row["paypal_email"];
    //var_dump($row);
    //echo json_encode($row);
    

  }
}

// Include paypal form
// include __DIR__ . '/forms/paypal.php';

<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                    <select id="PayPalAmount" required class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Choose Payment Service</option>
                        <option value="74">USD 10</option>    
                        <option value="76">RUB 100</option>   
                        <option value="77">RUB 500</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="col-sm" id="select"></div>
                                        
    <div class="col-sm"> 
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="js-button">
    Buy Now With PayPal        
</button>          
    </div>  
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var buyBtnPayPal = document.getElementById("js-button");

buyBtnPayPal.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    buyBtnPayPal.disabled = false;
    buyBtnPayPal.textContent = "Please wait...";
});
    
var select = document.getElementById("PayPalAmount");

select.addEventListener("change", function(){  
    getValue = this.value;
    // this в этом контексте - элемент, который запустил фукнцию. То же, что и select.value;
    //alert( getValue );
}); 

$('#js-button').click(function(){
    $('#select').empty();

    // ТА САМАЯ СТРОКА, ГДЕ НУЖНО ПОЛУЧИТЬ JSON С КОНКРЕТНЫМИ ДАННЫМИ
    var array = {cmd: '_xclick', business: 'book-facilitator@ya.ru', custom: '5'......};
    $.each(array, function(key, value) {
        $('#select').append('<input value="' + value + '" name="' + key + '">');
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, вы можете переложить весь массив из `php` в объект `js` и использовать его.

Для удобства массив php можно положить в другой, где ключами будут нужные id:

```
$services = [];
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row["payment_service"] == 'PayPal'){
        $services[$row["id"]] = $row;
    }
}
```

Затем получить его в js:

```
<script>
    // ...
    let getValue;
    // ...

    $('#js-button').click(function(){
        $('#select').empty();

        // ТА САМАЯ СТРОКА, ГДЕ НУЖНО ПОЛУЧИТЬ JSON С КОНКРЕТНЫМИ ДАННЫМИ
        let services = <?php echo json_encode($services); ?>;   // просто весь массив из php положить в объект js
        let array = services[getValue];     // и из него брать данные

        $.each(array, function(key, value) {
            $('#select').append('<input value="' + value + '" name="' + key + '">');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Вариант 2: не загружать массив сразу, а подгружать нужные данные ajax'ом при выборе значения из списка.